# Is there a hypernym for "gross" and "net"?

Tags: hypernyms

I am developing a software application that has a generic price object which has a boolean property that expresses whether or not that price includes VAT. Is there a better expression I can use than "grossness"? Not sure if what I am looking for is a hypernym, but I hope description makes it clear.

Comment: You could use "Taxed" and have a "Yes/No" answer.

Comment: "Gross" would be the total before taxes, discounts, coupons, etc. If this is supposed to specifically indicate whether the price includes VAT, consider "VatIncluded".

Comment: To be on topic, word requests should be accompanied be a literary context (eg a sentence or short paragraph) in which the word could be used.

Comment: ”VATincluded” certainly woks. Just “VAT” would too. For example, (VAT = true) means *the price includes VAT*, (VAT = false) means *the price has no VAT included*. Notice that your heading about a hypernym for gross and net does not match the direction of the comments. Either we are discussing the wrong thing or your question is wrong